# Setting TeXShop comment colors from command line

Tags: highlighting, texshop

I've updated to TeXShop 4.31 from 4.01 and the colors I've set from the command line as below are no longer respected, even though they are stored in `TeXShop.plist`. The comments are shown in red, not gray, as in before the update.

```
$ defaults write TeXShop commentred   0.5 
$ defaults write TeXShop commentgreen 0.5 
$ defaults write TeXShop commentblue  0.5 
$ defaults read TeXShop | grep comment
    commentblue = "0.5";
    commentgreen = "0.5";
    commentred = "0.5";
```

Is there a fix, besides setting the color interactively via the Themes preference panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of TeXShop tells me that theme colors are no longer stored in the Apple Preference System. The only way now to set colors is to set a Theme, either via the Themes preference panel or by placing a theme in `~/Library/TeXShop/Themes`.

Since theme files are simple text files, they are easy to edit.

The theme entry for comments is `SyntaxComment`, as in this sample from `DarkTheme.plist`:

```
<key>SyntaxComment</key>
<array>
        <real>0.42146489950144628</real>
        <real>0.48413497357315932</real>
        <real>0.48871422298063483</real>
        <real>1</real>
</array>
```

The three numbers are RGB as usual.